# How to qualify a peak on a surface (good or bad peak ?)

Tags: python, correlation, surface

I have some surfaces with a peak on them, when a "peak" is quite flat the quality should be "bad" and when a peak is defined by a high slope around its, it's a good one.
My surfaces are numpy array with the size of 241x241.

Bad quality:

[image: Bad quality]

Good quality:

[image: Good quality]

How can I quantify this ? I used the radius of a sphere fitting each surface, longer radius mean flatter surface. But I don't think it's the best way to do it (because the ideal case isn't a sphere but a peak which is more an ellipse). I think about a tangent, but where ? All around (360 degrees) the maximum point ? Which size of tangent ? 10 px around the maximum, 30px, 50px ?

For information, these surfaces comes from the template matching module providing by [Scikit](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html)

Comment: In statistics, [kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) measures something kind of like this, if you can normalize your array as a probability distribution in a way that make sense maybe you could use that (although I'm not sure how it would be computed exactly).

Comment: (this seems to be a relevant paper on the topic, if you can access it: [Characterization of surface roughness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0043164862900029))

Comment: A simple method could be to take the average after normalizing. Then low average means "good" peak.

Comment: @Jonas The problem with taking the average after normalizing, is that if there is no peak, the average can be low without any peak on the surface.

Comment: @jdehesa thank's for the paper I will read it.

Comment: @Lionel if you normalize first, ie divide all entries by the biggest one, than the average should be high. 1D example: your values are `[10, 20, 15]` (no peak) -> divide by `20` -> `[0.5, 1.0, 0.75]` -> average = `0.75`. with peak: `[1, 90, 2]` -> divide by 90 -> `[0.01, 1.0, 0.02]` -> average = `0.34` (lower)

Comment: you could also calculate the variance